# Selenium slow click action only localhost

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, automated-tests

I am running selenium locally, but it is extremely slow on find and click.

test_helper.rb

```
Capybara.register_driver :selenium do |app|
    Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, browser: :chrome)
end
```

This is a test on my page:

```
feature "dashboard" do
  include Warden::Test::Helpers
  scenario "test1", :js => true  do
    visit root_path
    visit new_user_session_path 
    #any of this are super slow
    #find("a[href='#{/users/sign_up}']").click
    #page.find(:css, 'a[href="/users/passsword/new"]').click
    #page.find(:xpath, "//a[@href='/users/sign_up']").click
   end
```

However, the visit action is almost instantly.

I've tried another test:

```
feature "dashboard" do
  include Warden::Test::Helpers
  scenario "test1", :js => true  do
    visit 'http://www.google.com.uy'
    page.find(:xpath, "//a[@href='//www.google.com.uy/intl/es-419/about.html?fg=1']").click
   end
```

And it worked.

How can I find the cause on my site? The new_user_session_path is devise's default template and controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to disable Turbolinks. Capybara worked but was slow when executing commands through byebug