# Selenium Slow After Many Execution

Tags: java, selenium

I am using selenium for automation. It works fast at first. But, after 10 or more runs, it starts to significantly slow down. It's so slow that populating a text field with 5 characters takes 30 seconds (as opposed to 1 second).

I saw a couple of post advising to make it sure that am using the right Win 32 or Win 64. But, I believe I am already using the right Win 32-bit for the laptop. A couple of posts advise upgrading. But, I believe I have the latest versions already. I just recently have my laptop and software downloaded 2 weeks ago. I have also checked the web driver processes but no multiple drivers are running (just one or none).

- Windows 7.0
- Selenium Java 3.6.0
- Internet Explorer 11
- Eclipse Oxygen.1a Release (4.7.1a)
- IE Web Driver 3.6.0 Win 32

Link 1: [webpage test with python selenium: really slow execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28067675/webpage-test-with-python-selenium-really-slow-execution)

Link 2: [Selenium slow click action only localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41764935/selenium-slow-click-action-only-localhost)

Comment: Can you post your code that illustrates the problem? Perhaps the function that is called repeatedly is the place to focus, but without seeing the code, it's difficult to help.

Answer (score 1):

After test/test run you should use driver.quit();
Probably you have many tasks of driver and machine hasn't enough memory.
if you run it in local machine you can try run in cmd "taskkill /F /IM chromedriver.exe /T"